# How to get two sums from a linq query

Tags: linq

### Summary

I have a list of Transactions.  Using Linq, I want to get a sum of the Cost and sum of the Quantity from this list in one query.

### Grouping

My first thought is to use grouping - but I don't really have a key that I want to group on, I want just one group with the results from the whole list.  So, I happen to have a property called "Parent" that will be the same for all of the transactions, so I'm using that to group on:

```
var totalCostQuery =
  (from t in Transactions
   where t.Status != GeneralStoreTransactionStatus.Inactive &&
   (t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Purchase ||
   t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Adjustment)
   group t by t.Parent into g
   select new
   {
     TotalCost = g.Sum(t => t.Cost.GetValueOrDefault()),
     TotalQuantity = g.Sum(t => t.Quantity.GetValueOrDefault())
   });
```

Grouping by t.Parent seems like it could be wrong. I really don't want to group at all, I just want the sum of t.Quantity and sum of t.Cost.

**Is that the correct way to get a sum of two different properties or can it be done in a different way.**

Comment: You can group by a constant value, e.g. `1`, rather than t.Parent. This way you will end up with a single group.

Comment: BTW, which flavor of Linq is it? Entity Framework? Linq to Objects?

Comment: I'm using linq against some entities returned by nHibernate.

Comment: so is this Linq to NHibernate? Or do you already have a list containing the results?

Comment: I already have a list, I'm just using Linq against the list I already fetched from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Linq to SQL or Entity Framework, you can do that:

```
var totalCostQuery =
  (from t in Transactions
   where t.Status != GeneralStoreTransactionStatus.Inactive &&
   (t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Purchase ||
   t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Adjustment)
   group t by 1 into g
   select new
   {
     TotalCost = g.Sum(t => t.Cost),
     TotalQuantity = g.Sum(t => t.Quantity)
   });
```

Note that you don't need to use `GetValueOrDefault`, null values will be ignored in the sum.

EDIT: not sure this works with Linq to NHibernate though...

---

Note that if you're using Linq to objects, the solution above won't be efficient, because it will enumerate each group twice (once for each sum). In that case you can use `Aggregate` instead:

```
var transactions =
   from t in Transactions
   where t.Status != GeneralStoreTransactionStatus.Inactive &&
   (t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Purchase ||
   t.Type == GeneralStoreTransactionType.Adjustment)
   select t;

var total = 
    transactions.Aggregate(
        new { TotalCost = 0.0, TotalQuantity = 0 },
        (acc, t) =>
        {
            TotalCost = acc.TotalCost + t.Cost.GetValueOrDefault(),
            TotalQuantity = acc.TotalQuantity + t.Quantity.GetValueOrDefault(),
        });
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of aggregate so thanks for that, I'll have to read up on it a bit more but looks like that is the way to go.  I didn't realize sum would ignore nulls, that's cool too.